# Seting up a cron job in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I went to Google's site on [cron's](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) and it looks like I can not set a cron job to run Mon-Fri every 10min from 07:00 to 15:00. Therefore I have 2 questions:

1) Can I have the cron job run every day, then have it not run on Sat and Sun, and then resume again on Mon-Fri?

2) If I can't do the first option, is there a way to have a cron job quit automatically?

Im am doing this in Python. If this isn't possible, is there a page I can look to for help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you lose the ability to specify ranges once you specify days, I think the best option would be to supply the time (`every 10 minutes from 07:00 to 15:00`) and then have a check in your script itself that checks the current date to determine if it is a weekday or not. You could do that with something simple like :

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> today.weekday()
1
```

Where `0` = Monday, `1` = Tuesday, etc. If your cron verified that the current weekday was `in (5, 6)`, then you could simply exit your program. One way of structuring this could be to link your cron to a simple function that checked the day - if a weekday, then your main function is called; if not, it ends. There may be a better way, but that's the best I can come up with right now :)

Comment: Thanks i'll try you suggestion. :)

Comment: @JamalMartin Sure thing :) Let me know if you run into any  issues or need more elaboration on the code (what I provided wasn't anything useful, just a proof-of-concept :) ).

Comment: so do I do this check in my cron.yaml? Sorry but im still learing how this works in app engine so im not a 100% sure of how to do this check.

Comment: @JamalMartin No prob - you would do that in your actual script (your cron is going to be attached to a script, so the check would be in there). Your cron.yaml would contain the timing instructions and then the URL to call (which is what points to your script). Does that make sense?

Comment: So I could do something like:
if today.weekday != 5 or 6
     then do stuff
else
    return

Comment: @JamalMartin Yeah, something like `if today.weekday() not in (5, 6): do stuff` (since you just want the function to end if it is 5 or 6, you could just stop there since in that case it won't enter the `if` block).

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat cheaper alternative. 
Run the CRON: every monday, tuesday, wednesday, thrursday, friday at 07:00
This weekday CRON starts a task (deferred or push), which will schedule a next task in 10 minutes until 15:00.

Comment: So I am still new to cron jobs and I don't really know what you mean with the deferred or push . Are you saying have a cron job run another cron job and if so how would you do that cause there is no example on google site, and I can't seem to find an example throw a internet search any resource would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: The weekday CRON job adds one task by queueing a task request to a push queue or the deferred queue. Deferred is very easy to use. At the end of such a task, the task will queue the next task, etc. See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push Clear?